# ArcGIS Server 10 on Ubuntu or CentOS?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, ubuntu, linux, centos

I know [Solaris](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/ArcGIS_10_and__101_Deprecation_Plan.pdf) is on the way out with 10.1

I also know that v10 is only [supported](http://wikis.esri.com/wiki/display/ag93bsr/ArcGIS+Server+Operating+System+Requirements+and+Limitations) on 32bit flavours of RedHat & SUSE.

What I do want to know, has anyone had any luck installing it on either [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) or [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/)?

Google only told me of this [blog](http://sagebrushgis.blogspot.com/2007/03/installing-arcgis-engine-92-java-on.html) which had revolved around Engine 9.2.

--EDIT--
Looks like Ubuntu support for may arrive at 10.1.  Ease of use and lower costs on AWS look to be the reasons (over CentOS)

[image]

Comment: Anyone stumbling on this link, might want to vote the idea up on ArcGIS Ideas here:
http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000088WyAAI

Comment: You might want to try [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb) until ESRI is ready for Ubuntu. (I don't know if it works, though.)

Comment: With Wine, it gets a [garbage rating](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=16568). :-(

Comment: See: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/arcgis-server-10-on-ubuntu-or-centos

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CentOS will work if you stick with a version that corresponds to [one of the supported versions of RHEL](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgisserver/10.0/arcgis-server-server-requirements) but I doubt you'll have much luck with Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to add to this old question and answer: as of ArcGIS 10.3 for Server, CentOS and a couple of other RHEL derived distributions have been added to the official support statement: http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/install/linux/system-requirements.htm

Answer (score 5):

I have it on a verbal authority from ESRI that they were looking at Ubuntu during the ArcGIS 10 Beta. so based on this it is in the pipeline but how far they have gotten I could only speculate

Answer (score 3):

While the ArcGIs 9.4 (later 10) Beta was underway I was made aware that Esri was looking into Ubuntu but at this stage it is not supported, and does not work.

In saying this it does depend on which portion of ArcGIS Server you are looking at. If you are looking at the database portion, then you can install the database on your Ubuntu Server and then install SDE on another machine pointing to your database. At this stage this is the only way Ubuntu can be included in the server operations of ArcGIS Server.

Sorry for the bad news,
CDB

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is as soon as you install any OS to the VirtualBox it will be a non-licensed copy or it will cost as licensed. It would be better to install ArcGIS to a Ubuntu computer itself without anything in between ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thread in Ubuntu forums where several people say they've had success running ArcGIS on Ubuntu machines via VirtualBox:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=553968

-Trevor

Comment: That is certainly possible. In fact I would recommend using a Centos VM and not windows, because you could use paravirtualisation (KVM,Xen) which will offer better performance.